# Better code for converting a char to its UTF-8 percent encoding representation?

Tags: java, guava, utf-8

This is working code for a URI template (RFC 6570) implementation; when the character to render is not within a specific character set, it is needed to grab the UTF-8 representation of that character and encode each byte as a percent-encoded sequence.

The question is whether something more efficient than this exists?

```
private static String encodeChar(final char c)
{
    final String tmp = new String(new char[] { c });
    final byte[] bytes = tmp.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (final byte b: bytes)
        sb.append('%').append(UnsignedBytes.toString(b, 16));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Note: `UnsignedBytes.toString()` is from Guava.

Comment: What kind of performance do you need? Is this just a general question? Did you try essentially the same thing on the whole string and see if it was faster?

Comment: Doing it on a whole string is a no-no. Only the characters out of a specified character set need to be percent-encoded this way. What I am asking is whether a better way to achieve such an encoding of a single character exists. For reference, see RFC 6570, section 1.5.

Comment: Of course, on a whole string it would skip most characters - I don't know how easy it would be with getBytes. (You didn't answer my first two questions.)

Comment: It is not a question of performance; the problem is that I think the code is a little clumsy as it stands. In this sense it is more of a general question. The main encoding function uses a `CharMatcher` to determine whether the current character in a string should be percent encoded or not.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode("a?>éàùA-Z",
                    System.getProperty("sun.jnu.encoding")));
        } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println("BIG PB");
            return; 
        }
    }
```

Output :

> a%3F%3E%E9%E0%F9A-Z

You have the same for [URLEDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)

**EDIT**

*For URI*
Found in src  of [iMeMex Dataspace ManagementSystem](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imemex/?source=dlp)

```
public static URI encode(String uriStr) throws URISyntaxException {
    if (uriStr != null) {
        // poor man's encoding
        uriStr = uriStr.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    }
    return new URI(uriStr);
}
```

[JavaDoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)

But URI from Java does not change other %VALUES.

Comment: This does not fit the bill. For instance, it replaces spaces with '+', and the encoded character list differs from what URI Template requires.